# How to get the duration time of object tag in jQuery and play video in specific time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

```
<div id="sound" >
  <OBJECT  classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" WIDTH="0" HEIGHT="0" id="Yourfilename" ALIGN="">
    <PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="sample.swf"> 
    <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high>
    <PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#333399> 
    <EMBED src="sample.swf" quality=high bgcolor=#333399 WIDTH="0" HEIGHT="0" NAME="Yourfilename" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">

    </EMBED> 

  </OBJECT> 
</div>
```

I want to get the duration time of this sound, and convert it to seconds, then play this sound from a specific time.

For example, playing this sound from 40 seconds.

How can I do it?

Comment: I know nothing about Flash but I would think that as it is an embedded resource which is executed by a plug-in there will be no way jQuery can determine the length of the `.swf` movie. It could be a game, or a sound or a continuous loop, ie of indeterminate length. I stand to be corrected of course :)

Comment: if i used Html5 tag like <audio> , how to solve this problem

Comment: <audio controls="controls">
  <source src="sample.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="sample.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have been told previously, don't use deprecated tags, and try to use the fresh `<audio>` tag from HTML5 for doing that.

You'll have to call `audio.duration`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559276/how-can-i-constantly-update-the-duration-of-this-mp3-file-im-playing-with-js-t) already answered question from this same site. Try something like this:

```
$(audio).bind('timeupdate', function() {
...
parseInt(audio.duration - audio.currentTime, 10),
...
position = (audio.currentTime / audio.duration) * 100,
```

Good luck.

Edited: If you want to start after, i.e., 20 seconds, you shall call to `audioElement.currentTime=20;` and then calling to `audioElement.play();` at your js `$(document).ready(function())`. Ask if you need anything else.

Comment: *i'm trying to solve this problem but till now i can't. when i used alert(parseInt(audio.duration - audio.currentTime, 20).toString()) it return NAN . *

Comment: NaN (Not-a-Number) error ([check](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html)) is returned when you grab no number or that property from `audio.duration` is not enabled. If so, please make a try with other browser. Some users have reported this as a bug on bugzilla'.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var audio = $('audio');
  $(audio).bind('timeupdate', function() {
    parseInt(audio.duration - audio.currentTime, 20).toString();
    position = (audio.currentTime / audio.duration) * 100;
  });
audio.play();
});
```

I'm trying to solve this problem but till now i can't. When I used

```
alert(parseInt(audio.duration - audio.currentTime, 20).toString())
```

it returns NAN .